# Im not able to edit the timeout on Selenium Standalone

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, gulp, webdriver-io

I'm trying to create a test Automation with webdriverio, selenium standalone and Gulp. Selenium is running within the app, but I can't edit the selenium timeout default value. The page loads fine, but it's super slow and I get the default 10 second timeout. How can I edit the TimeOut?

Here is my code to load the Selenium server. 
**gulpfile.babel**

```
import gulp from 'gulp';
import selenium from 'selenium-standalone';
import webdriver from 'gulp-webdriver';

let seleniumServer;

gulp.task('selenium:start', (done) => {
    selenium.install({ logger: function(message) {} }, () => {
        selenium.start((err, child) => {
            if (err) { return done(err); }
            seleniumServer = child;
            done();
        });
    });

});

gulp.task('config:setup', ['selenium:start'], () => {
    return gulp.src('wdio.conf.js')
        .pipe(webdriver({
            waitforTimeout: 60000
        })).on('error', () => {
            seleniumServer.kill();
            process.exit(1);
        });
});
gulp.task('handler', ['config:setup'], () => {
    seleniumServer.kill();
});
```

**My Test case**

```
describe('Creating a new invitation request', function() {
    let _page, _container;
    before(() => {
        _page = new page.page();
        _container = new container.container();

    });
    it('request invitation', function() {
        _page.navigate(_container.urlBase);
        expect(_page.createNewRequest(_container.userToCreate));
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

## Edited, added the wdio.conf.js

```
exports.config = {
    specs: [
        './testcases/*.js'
    ],
    exclude: [      
        './excluded/out/*.js'
    ],
    maxInstances: 1,
capabilities:
    capabilities: [{      
        maxInstances: 1,
        browserName: 'chrome'
    }],
    sync: true,
    logLevel: 'silent',
    coloredLogs: true,
    screenshotPath: './errorShots/',
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost',
    waitforTimeout: 90000,
    connectionRetryTimeout: 90000,
    connectionRetryCount: 3,
    framework: 'mocha',
    mochaOpts: {
        compilers: ['js:babel-core/register']
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your default timeout in `wdio.conf.js` file . Have you tried to change that?

Comment: also try to use `client.pause(milliseconds);` to pause for execution of commands

Comment: I did change the `wdio.conf.js`, I put 90 seconds and yet the selenium driver  only wait for 10seconds.

Comment: just small note that it takes time milliseconds. just mentioning as you mentioned your time in secs. whats the testing framework you are using with webdriverio? it may be the default framework timeout set to 10s.

Comment: I changed all defaults to 90,000 milliseconds = 90 secs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the `wdio.conf.js` file, on `mochaOpts` attribute added `timeout` with the milliseconds desired under the `compiler` options.
The config ended up like this:

```
  exports.config = {
    specs: [
        './testcases/*.js'
    ],
    exclude: [      
        './excluded/out/*.js'
    ],
    maxInstances: 1,
capabilities:
    capabilities: [{      
        maxInstances: 1,
        browserName: 'chrome'
    }],
    sync: true,
    logLevel: 'silent',
    coloredLogs: true,
    screenshotPath: './errorShots/',
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost',
    waitforTimeout: 90000,
    connectionRetryTimeout: 90000,
    connectionRetryCount: 3,
    framework: 'mocha',
    mochaOpts: {
        compilers: ['js:babel-core/register'],
        timeout: 90000
    }
}
```